# Copying all files from source folder to destination folder renaming all the files while coping in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to transfer images from **"SourceFolder/Images"** to the **"DestinationFolder/Photos"** in **asp.net c#**. All the images in the source folder should be copied to destination renaming the original image name with newly generated name. For example, if a file in source folder is mountain.jpg and while coping this image name to destination folder, it need to be renamed as Current DateTime followed by underscore and original filename (2016-05-20_mountain.jpg).

My code is as below:

```cs
        string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/SourceFolder/Images");
        string targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/DestinationFolder/Photos");           
        foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
        {                
            File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath), true);
        }
```

Above code successfully copies all files to target path with same name as original name, but I want to rename each file to different name while transferring the file names to destination.

Comment: What is your actual question here?  "I was trying since long but unable to success." doesn't say anything about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have change your code as folowing :

```
    string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/SourceFolder/Images");
    string targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/DestinationFolder/Photos");

    foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
    {

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(srcPath);
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + fileInfo.Name;

        File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath).Replace(fileInfo.Name, fileName), true);
    }
```

or you can use also :

```
    string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/SourceFolder/Images");
    string targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/DestinationFolder/Photos");

    foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
    {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(srcPath);
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), fileInfo.Name);

            File.Copy(srcPath, string.Format("{0}/{1}", targetPath, fileName), true);
    }
```

you can change the DateTime format as you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
  static void CopytoDestination(string sourcePath,string sourcePath)
    {
        string fileName = "test.txt";

        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

        // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory.
        // Get the files in the source folder. (To recursively iterate through
        // all subfolders under the current directory, see
        // "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree.")
        // Note: Check for target path was performed previously
        //       in this code example.
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
        }

        // Keep console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
   protected void btnTransferFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/SourceFolder/Images");
        string targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/DestinationFolder/Photos");

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            string destFile = string.Empty;

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);

                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
            }
        }
    }
```